# Ruby method doesn't get array parameter

Tags: ruby, rspec, parameters

```
describe Array do
  describe "#sum" do
    it "has a #sum method" do
      expect([]).to respond_to(:sum)
    end

    it "should be 0 for an empty array" do
      expect([].sum).to eq(0)
    end

    it "should add all of the elements" do
      expect([1,2,4].sum).to eq(7)
    end
  end
end
```

the code above is the test code given to me. and I made the code below to be tested by the test code.

```
class Array

    def initialize(arr)
        @arr = arr    
    end

    def sum
        if @arr == nil
            return 0
        else
            numArr = @arr
            total = 0 
            numArr.each {|num|
                total += num
            }
            return total
        end
    end
end
```

I thought it would return total 7. (1+2+4 = 7) but it returns 0... I guess it doesn't take [1,2,4] array as a parameter. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the existing array class already has an initializer, and self inside the instance of an array already is an array, you don't need to add your own initializer

```
class Array

  def sum
    self.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x }
  end

end
```

should do what you want. Lookup inject if it isn't clear, but it does essentially the same that you tried to do with your code, just that you were using a local variable to store the sum.

If this is not only an experiment however I recommend not do monkey patches on core classes if avoidable (and it usually is avoidable). Here's an article with some hints how to do it a bit cleaner, if not avoidable: http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/

Comment: I have one more question, if you don't mind. so you said it has already initialize in it, and what if I want to get only [1,2,4] the array itself? how can I access it? (in your answer above, how does 'x' get the array [1,2,4]?

Comment: In the example above 'self' is referencing the array.
'def sum' is an instance method, so self inside this method refers to the instance of the array - In this case [1, 2, 4]

What inject does is basically defining sum = 0; then iterating through the array (x always being one element in the array).